# Add line to matrix in pine script

Tags: matrix, pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why is a row not added to the line matrix but to int matrix?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Matrix test", overlay = true)

if barstate.islast
    mInt = matrix.new<int>(1, 1, na)
    matrix.add_row(mInt)
    
    mLine = matrix.new<line>(1, 1, na)
    matrix.add_row(mLine)
    
    t = table.new(position.middle_right, 1, 2)
    table.cell(t, 0, 0, str.tostring(matrix.rows(mInt)))
    table.cell(t, 0, 1, str.tostring(matrix.rows(mLine)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug. I think Tradingview will handle this.
You can add array with `na` lines as a workaround:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Matrixtest")

if barstate.islast   
    mLine2 = matrix.new<line>(1, 1, na)
    line l = na
    a = array.new<line>()
    array.push(a, l)
    matrix.add_row(mLine2, 0, a)
    label.new(bar_index, low, "LINE matrix: " + str.tostring(matrix.rows(mLine2)) + "x" + str.tostring(matrix.columns(mLine2)))
```